# clean url in php creating error in loading page

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is the link below I want to clean in my website with a rewrite.

```
http://www example.com/detail.php?url=personname
```

and I am using this rewrite code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Header unset ETag

FileETag None

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
 # Turn mod_rewrite  on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+detail\.php\?url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ detail/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^detail/([^/]+)/?$ detail.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

the code work properly and url change to this 
`http://www example.com/detail/personname` but the detail of person is not showing:

and all the url of the page get change to this `http://www example.com/detail/detail.php?url=personname`  can you guide me little in this matter

Comment: Nothing to do with php, please remove this tag...